# How can I add a query by array index in scala slick?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-pg

Using scala slick, how would you generate a query filter using plain text?
Context -
I'm trying to filter on an array position column, doesn't appear to be supported by the slick extensions provided by https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg.

I.e. we have an array field:

```
   id UUID,
   name varchar,
   my_array_field varchar[],
   ...
```

And I'd like to be able to query by the sql equivalent of
`SELECT FROM BLAH where name='somename' and my_array_field[2] = 'bar'`

- Is there a way to just inject a text string as a filter? i.e. not the slick sql interpolator for a query, but just a filter element?
- Is there a slick or slick-pg representation of retrieving by an array element?

Answer (score 0):

In the README of [slick-pg](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg) you can see at the [usage](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg#usage) section an example of how to use the lib. You would need to mix `PgArraySupport` to the profile and `ArrayImplicits` to the `API`.

> ```scala
> trait MyPostgresProfile extends ExPostgresProfile
>                            with PgArraySupport
>
>   override val api = MyAPI
>
>   object MyAPI extends ExtPostgresAPI with ArrayImplicits
> }
>
> object MyPostgresProfile extends MyPostgresProfile
> ```

Then you can see the array column defined as `def tags = column[List[String]]("tags_arr")` and the method `byTag` using a filter `.filter(_.tags @& tags.toList.bind)`.

> ```scala
> import MyPostgresProfile.api._
>
> class TestTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Test](tag, Some("xxx"), "Test") {
>   def tags = column[List[String]]("tags_arr")
>   def * = (tags) <> (Test.tupled, Test.unapply)
> }
>
> object tests extends TableQuery(new TestTable(_)) {
>   // will generate sql like:
>   //   select * from test where tags && ?
>   def byTag(tags: String*) = tests
>     .filter(_.tags @& tags.toList.bind)
>     .map(t => t)
> }
> ```

There is also a [README - Supported Array Oper/Functions](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/com/github/tminglei/slickpg/array/README.md) you can check.